# Digit signed out when rebuild/relaunch and Error -34018 in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, twitter-digits, fabric-digits

I got `error -34018` in `AppDelegate` when checking the `Digits.sharedInstance().session()` is nill or not. Application is not crashing, it just shows this error on Output. I used `Digit.session()` to identify whether the user sign in or not. So after a successful Digit phone number sign in I just relauch / rebuilt the app, but when relaunch the application the application shows it's not contain any shared instance. and identify as user is not logged in. This code is working on xcode 7, but shows this error on xcode 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this in my app by adding Keychain Access Groups to the Entitlements file. I turned on the Keychain Sharing switch in the Capabilities section in app, and it is working perfectly.

[image]